# Wordpress Create Frontend pages with plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

So I need some help with a plugin I'm currently working on. Basically I built a plugin for WP with its own unique tables, as opposed to using a custom post type. The reason is because I needed a few relationships between the databases. So now I've got all of the backend information connected and working, and now I'm trying to display it on the front-end of Wordpress. I'm not sure how to even phrase what I'm trying to do, but basically I want to be able to display the database information when a user accesses a specific url without having to create a WP page and add a shortcode or adding a template file. How would I go about doing something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress' wpdb functions to query any database that you have created. This can be on any page/template within wordpress.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

```
function displayStuff(){
  global $wpdb;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM yourdatabase";
  $results = $wpdb->query($query);
}
```

If using outside of wordpress, just use standard php mysql_connect & mysql_query, or include wordpress in your page:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php');
```